# Comparing two datetimes in MySQL JSON

Tags: mysql, mysql-json

I have a MySQL table called "contract" with a JSON-type column.

The data in this column looks like this:

```
{"5": "1663966800"}
```

This property is a UTC time in seconds, stored as text.

I am looking to query the table to see all entries where this property is greater than the current datetime.

What is the proper query for this?

I am trying to run the below and getting an "Invalid JSON path expression" error:

```
select `contract`.* from `contract` 
where contract.id != 0  
AND (contract.data->'$.5' > "1687893018")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are very close. When using JSON data in MySQL, the -> operator can be used to extract a value from a JSON column. But since the value you're extracting is a string (not a number), you'll need to cast it as unsigned in order to perform the comparison.

```
SELECT `contract`.*
FROM `contract`
WHERE JSON_EXTRACT(`contract`.`data`, '$."5"') IS NOT NULL
AND CAST(JSON_EXTRACT(`contract`.`data`, '$."5"') AS UNSIGNED) > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW());
```